# Подключение pdo drivers

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, друзья! У меня проблема следующая, не могу подключить драйверы pdo все необходимые. Пишу следующий код:

```
echo var_dump(pdo_drivers());
```

Выводится следующий массив:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "mysql" }
```

Хотя в php.ini подключил следующие библиотеки:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

И в папке ext лежат все вышеуказанные библиотеки, нужных версий. Помогите подключить,
чтобы все работало. К примеру чтобы функция oci_connect работала. Спасибо заранее за все ответы и комментарии.

Comment: А у вас есть возможность изменять php.ini? Просто многие (если не большинство) хостингов запрещают конфигурировать сервер с помощью этого файлика

Comment: А сервер перезапускали после правки? php.ini точно тот правите (phpinfo() вам подскажет)? в логах ошибок о несовместимости версий нет?

Comment: Перезапускал конечно. Выявилась ошибка, дело в том что у меня стоит денвер Denwer3_Base_PHP52_2013-06-02_a2.2.22_p5.2.12_zendoptimizer_m5.5.25_pma3.5.1_xdebug вот в этой сборке вываливает ошибку сейчас "Точка входа в процедуру php_pdo_unregister_driver" не найдена в библиотеке php5ts.dll. Кто с такой сталкивался ошибкой?

Comment: Переставил на сборку Denwer3_Base_2013-06-02_a2.2.22_p5.3.13_m5.5.25_pma3.5.1_xdebug, все равно php_pdo_oci.dll не работает, и соответственно функции из нее не определяются. Подскажите что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Советую поставить Open Server последней версии, а не устаревший денвер.. В опен сервере PDO у меня все работает.